Setting gdm settings through dconf has no effect
I've been trying to disable-user-list at user logon guided by various solutions:

GNOME official docs
RedHat
Fostips
and many others that were actually copy-pasted articles

This seems to be an old story, but whatever I tried through dconf profiles and databases just didn't work. So my question is - why?
Ubuntu 23.10

Why would that be a hack to modify configuration files? At the time of posting the bug I found, the "official" way didn't work in 17.10 and 18.04.
But setting disable-user-list=true in /usr/share/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults seems to be the right way to accomplish this and is working as expected in version 18.04 and newer. Just make sure the section line [org/gnome/login-screen] is not commented out.
Doing it through the GUI won't work since you would set it on your own user and not system-wide.

The only solution that actually worked for me was provided by @Joris Le Blansch (j-leblansch) here:

uncomment a few lines in /usr/share/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults
re-login

But, to me, this seems to be rather a hack than a proper admin-wise solution.
